# ElementToBeClickable 'not working'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, dc);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,60));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com/ncr");
string xpath = "//*[@id=\"lst-ib\"]";  // the google search text box
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));
//wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
element.Click();
element.SendKeys("some text");
```

The above code, works as is. However, if I uncomment the wait.Until then the browser opens, but no text is sent. It seems to 'stop' at the wait.Until. No idea what I am doing wrong. It is not a problem for the current use case, but would be nice to know how to do it correctly for future uses.

EDIT:
After doing a little searching and testing, I found the following code works specifically for RemoteWebDriver.

```
IWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(uri, dc);
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name(name));
```

It works when the "name" exists in the DOM, and throws an exception when I modify "name" to something not in the DOM, as would be expected. 
Thanks @DebanjanB for sending me in the right direction.

Comment: Is it possible that you can not check if an element is clickable because it is a textbox (or more correct, you can try to wait for it, but a textbox will never be clickable and code will timeout)? You have the code `element.Click()` but it is possible it doesn't do anything. And that arose no problem, until you tell selenium to wait for the textbox to be clickable, but it can't happen. Why don't you wait for it to be visible for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the **`WebElement`** represented as **`Search Box`** on **`Google Home Page`**, the element is as follows :

```
<input class="gsfi" id="lst-ib" maxlength="2048" name="q" autocomplete="off" title="Search" type="text" value="" aria-label="Search" aria-haspopup="false" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" style="border: none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: auto; width: 100%; background: url(&quot;data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAID/AMDAwAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw%3D%3D&quot;) transparent; position: absolute; z-index: 6; left: 0px; outline: none;">
```

A couple of things about the **`Search Box`** :

1. It's an **`<input>`** tag which will accept only **`text`**
2. An **`<input>`** tag won't have any **`onClick()`** event associated with it like the **`<button>`** or **`<a>`** tags.
3. So a proper clause for **`ExpectedConditions`** can be **`ElementIsVisible`** instead of `ElementToBeClickable`.
4. **`ElementIsVisible`** clause will ensure that the `an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible.`

> **`Visibility`** means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

### Update :

As you mentioned that you are getting the same result, so I will make some simple tweaks to your code and write the equivalent code as :

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Name("q")));
element.SendKeys("some text");
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. I changed the line to wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(xpath))); but i am getting the same result.

Comment: No unfortunately I am getting the same result. 
Interestingly, your code works when I use FirefoxDriver but not RemoteWebDriver. I've been Googling like crazy but can't seem to find why that might be.

Answer (score -1):

can you please try the below code. Its working fine.

```
public static void search() throws Throwable
    {
        WebElement SearchBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_SmallSearchInputBox1_csr_sbox']"));
        SearchBox.clear();
        SearchBox.sendKeys("Text");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(8000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement SearchLink=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_PlaceHolderSearchArea_SmallSearchInputBox1_csr_SearchLink']"));
        SearchLink.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.navigate().back();   
    }
```

do let me know in case you face any challenges

Comment: this does not answer the question